# Restoring Mongodb database in Windows by using dump taken from Ubuntu server

Tags: mongodb

I have taken a dump from Ubuntu v20 server using mongodump. I need to use it on my Windows laptop.

In my Windows laptop,

a. from which directory should I execute the mongorestore command?

b. where should the dump folder be saved?

When I try to execute the mongorestore command from my projects directory in windows, it does not recognize the command.

I also tried to do the same from C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin, but got the same error.

```
ERROR: <mongorestore : The term 'mongorestore' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.>
```

Comment: FYI this is off-topic here. Possibly fitting for [dba.se] (just read the guidelines there first). As for not finding `mongorestore` - this seems like more of an installation or general usage issue (and you’ve shown no details except for error output)

Comment: Have you installed the [MongoDB Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/#installation) on your Windows machine?

Comment: Yeah, DB Tools were not installed. Now its working fine.